# Unable Update row in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm not sure what am I doing wrong, however when I try to make an update with my API to my database the data is not being updated, I already checked if the name of my table or the name of the columns match and everything looks ok, I also checked if the data it's being received and yes, it is, however it is not updating, do you guys see the error in my code?

```
$msg['message'] = '';
$storeId = $data->storeId;
$id = $data->id;
//UPDATE CLIENT BY ID
$db_connection = new Database();
$conn = $db_connection->dbConnection();
$update_post = "UPDATE `client` SET name = :name, lastName = :lastName, phoneNumber = :phoneNumber, contactEmail = :contactEmail, address = :address,  taxId = :taxId WHERE id = :id";
$update_post_stmt = $conn->prepare($update_post);
//DATA BINDING
$update_post_stmt->bindValue(':name', $data->name,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$update_post_stmt->bindValue(':lastName', $data->lastName,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$update_post_stmt->bindValue(':phoneNumber', $data->phoneNumber,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$update_post_stmt->bindValue(':contactEmail', $data->contactEmail,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$update_post_stmt->bindValue(':address', $data->address,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$update_post_stmt->bindValue(':taxId', $data->taxId,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$update_post_stmt->bindValue(':id', $data->id,PDO::PARAM_INT);

if($update_post_stmt->execute()){
    $msg['message'] = 'Updated Successfully';
}else{
    $msg['message'] = 'Unable to Update';
}
$closeConnection = $db_connection->closeInstance($conn);
// ECHO MESSAGE IN JSON FORMAT
echo  json_encode($msg);
```

[image]

By the way, I'm getting the "Updated Successfully" message

[image]

Comment: Are you getting `Updated successfully` or `Unable to Updated`? When the query fails, you should log the SQL error message to see the reason.

Comment: Yes, Im Getting Updated Successfully

Comment: This question is off topic and should be closed. It's an observational error, not a program error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing that stands out to me on this is you are declaring your "type" for each field as a `PDO::Param_Int`, meaning that it is trying to take in your "name", "lastname", "emailaddress", and "address" as an integer instead of a string.  This would likely lead to a type-casting error in your code. Try replacing those fields with `PDO::PARAM_STR`, and you should be closer to a resolution. I believe the data binding will wrap things in the appropriate strings for you as well.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated it but still not updating the data, not sure why when I execute() trows TRUE

Comment: Check this comment https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php#81681 to show where your failure is. You should be using count for update-successful

Comment: Thanks Aaron, I've tried to upload once again my php file with the error that you found and it is working now, thanks for your help and time!

Comment: Just to let you know, this is not a issue, param int doesn't cast your string to int.

Comment: @YourCommonSense he has updated his initial question: he had it backwards and was casting everything as an int. Check the question history

Comment: Again: setting param int **does not** cast your data to int. Try it yourself and see. Besides, his alleged problem is not "all my strings are updated to 0s" as it would have been if it was the case, but "I think my data is not updated at all" which directly contradicts with your answer